# Potentially excessive state and use of bind

Tags: javascript, react.js

The purpose of the code is to see if a form element would get data from internal react components and it did. It was also to see how clean I could make an autocomplete component.

The autocomplete has 4 states and I use bind excessively (is this bad?). I also added a function `updateSpecificState`, because I found it inconvenient that React has no method to let you change a specific property in the state.

app.js:

```
React.render(
    <Rendrform method="post" />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

rendrform.js: (don't worry about the name, I confused rendr and react)

```
var Rendrform = React.createClass({
    onSubmit: function(event) {
        console.log('I would ajax this:', $(event.target).serialize());
        event.preventDefault();
    },
    render: function() {
        var types = [
            {title: 'blog', id: 11,},
            {title: 'comment', id: 22,},
            {title: 'todo', id: 33,},
        ];
        var mappingTo = function(option) {
            return option.id;
        };
        var mappingFrom = function(option) {
            return option.title;
        };
        return (
            <form method={this.props.method} target="index.html" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <input type="text" name="author" placeholder="Enter Author" />
                <Autocomplete options={types} mappingTo={mappingTo} mappingFrom={mappingFrom} name="type" />
                <textarea name="body"></textarea><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Post" />
            </form>
        );
    }
});
```

autocomplete.js:

```
//TODO: by default options would be an array of strings,with no mapping
//TODO: the user can define mappingTo and/or mappingFrom, which both can either be a string or a function. String would be the key
var Autocomplete = React.createClass({
    //Feels like this should be a native function...
    updateSpecificState: function(object, key, value) {
        object[key] = value;
        this.setState(object);
        console.log('Current State: ', this.state);
        console.log('Current State.value: ', this.state.value);
    },
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            display: 'none',
            filteredOptions: this.props.options,
            value: null,
            faceValue: '',
        };
    },
    setValue: function(option) {
        this.updateSpecificState(this.state, 'value', this.props.mappingTo(option));
        this.updateSpecificState(this.state, 'faceValue', this.props.mappingFrom(option));
    },
    /* TODO: make a toggle mixin for events or something... */
    onFocus: function() {
        this.updateSpecificState(this.state, 'display', 'block');
    },
    blurTimer: false,
    onBlur: function() {
        //otherwise the blur happens bfore the click event
        this.blurTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
            this.updateSpecificState(this.state, 'display', 'none');
            if(!this.state.value)
                this.updateSpecificState(this.state, 'faceValue', '');
        }.bind(this), 200);
    },
    onClick: function(event) {
        this.setValue(this.props.options[event.target.dataset.index]);
        window.clearTimeout(this.blurTimer);
        this.updateSpecificState(this.state, 'display', 'none');
    },
    onChange: function(event) {
        this.updateSpecificState(this.state, 'faceValue', event.target.value);
        this.updateSpecificState(this.state, 'filteredOptions', this.props.options.filter(function(option) {
            return option.title.indexOf(this.state.faceValue) != -1;
        }.bind(this)));
        //Note: If performance is an issue, then I could return here if the above filter returns more than 1.
        var exactOptionMatches = this.props.options.filter(function(option) {
            return option.title === this.state.faceValue;
        }.bind(this));
        if(exactOptionMatches.length >= 1)
            this.setValue(exactOptionMatches[0]);
        else
            this.updateSpecificState(this.state, 'value', null);
    },
    render: function() {
        var faceValue = this.state.faceValue;
        return (
            <div>
                <input type="text" onFocus={this.onFocus} onBlur={this.onBlur} onChange={this.onChange} value={faceValue} />
                <input type="hidden" name={this.props.name} value={this.state.value} />
                <div className="autocomplete-items" style={{display: this.state.display}}>
                    {this.state.filteredOptions.map(function(option, i) {
                        return <div data-index={i} onClick={this.onClick}>{this.props.mappingFrom(option)}</div>;
                    }.bind(this))}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },
});
```

Comment: I could remove the filteredOptions state, but the only way I could do that was to add filtering to both the HTML and the onClick... the issue being the daata attribute that i use to reference the specific option object. (also an issue might be that it's 4:30am)

Comment: awww no advice :( I'm new with reactJS and was hoping to get better with it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to bind those Array.map/filter calls explicitly.  Array.map/filter take an option 'thisArg': `Array.map(function () {}, this);`

Or you can just make those 4 functions React Class functions instead of anonymous so they get explicitly bound to `this` when the ReactElement is instantiated.